# When using CrudRepository how can I use transformers

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have read this article
https://smarterco.de/spring-data-jpa-query-result-to-dto/

And tried this.

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User AS u")
    List<User> findAll();

    @Query("SELECT new de.smarterco.example.dto.UserNameDTO(u.id, u.name) FROM User u WHERE u.name = :name")
    List<UserNameDTO> retrieveUsernameAsDTO(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

And it works.

But lets say my User had a list of Address. And my `UserNameDTO` also had a corresponding dto. How could I do that?

Can I somehow attach a resultTransformer to the query? or register a converter?

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Best regards. Ole Bille